# Table width to \linewidth in twocolumn environment

Tags: tables

I tried make a table whose width is one-column linewidth in twocolumn environment. So I used `table*` and `tabular*`.

```
\begin{table*}[t] 
caption{Some captions...}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|l|l|l|}\hline
Table contents...
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
```

But it gives me an output whose right vertical line is not properly positioned:

[image: wrong]

Would you tell me why this happens or recommend another method to do it?

Comment: Maybe try with `tabularx`?

Comment: @Bernard If I use `tabularx`, the table is fitted to the half of linewidth since it is in `twocolumn` environment.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this point. You can use the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package, and nest `tabularx` in this environment to use the whole text width.